# Ctrl+Y (Redo) not working in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Recently switched to Visual Studio 2019.  For some reason Ctrl+Y deletes the current line rather than implementing Redo.  If I pull down the Edit menu, selecting the "Redo (Ctrl+Y)" menu item works. But not the indicated keyboard shortcut.

Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Ctrl+Y might be bound to another command as well, taking higher precedence.  You can use steps 1-3 in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-menu-items?view=vs-2019#to-verify-the-availability-of-a-keyboard-shortcut) to see what commands are using Ctrl+Y.

Comment: @Jimmy, on step 3 it confirmed that Ctrl+Y is used by "Edit.Redo(Ctrl+Y (Global))".  VS2019 remains firmly convinced that Ctrl+Y will execute Edit.Redo but all it does is delete the current line for me.

Comment: The default in visual studio seems to be set such that Edit.Redo (Global) and Edit.LineDelete (TextEditor) have the same default shortcut of Ctrl+Y.  
This seems strange toe me!

Comment: @ChrisNevill Thank you!  While it was not assigned to Edit.LineDelete your comment prompted me to see if it was used somewhere else.  Installed Keyboard Shortcut Exporter from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.KeyboardShortcutExporter, exported all shortcuts, and found that it was being used by Edit.LineCut.  Once I deleted that shortcut then CTRL+Y **finally** started working for Redo!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dan H above. In Tools>Customize>Keyboard, remove the keyboard shortcuts for Edit.LineCut and Edit.LineDelete. Assign Edit.Redo to CTRL-Y and redo works again.

Thanks Dan!